# Hibernate bidirectional @OneToOne always EAGER on child side

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities: Person and Passport. I map it as bidirectional.

Passport (parent):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "passports")
public class Passport {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private Integer serial;
    private Integer number;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Person person;
```

Person (child):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Passport passport;
```

Both relations fetch types are LAZY.

Now I'm trying to find only child:

```
Person p = entityManager.find(Person.class, 1);
System.out.println(p.getName());
```

Hibernate generates two SELECT statements instead of one (must select only person).

```
Hibernate: select p1_0.id,p1_0.name from people p1_0 where p1_0.id=?
Hibernate: select p1_0.id,p1_0.number,p1_0.person_id,p1_0.serial from passports p1_0 where p1_0.person_id=?
```

I expect only one select, but get two.

Why doesnt LAZY work?
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all other relation types, `FetchType.LAZY` will work as expected, but for `@OneToOne` it is different.

It would work if you change your `Person` entity such that you don't have relation to `Passport`, and in `Passport` have:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@MapsId
private Person person;
```

Then if you are using Spring JPA and you want to find a `Passport` for a `Person`, you can do `passportRepository.findByPerson(person)`.

Or if you are using `entityManager`, you can find it as:

```
entityManager.find(Passport.class, person.getId());
```

For more explanation, please read https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-lazy-loading-one-to-one/.